Assembly question ISA
I am studying for a exam in Computer Architecture and one of the exercises says this:
write the assembly code which calculates the equation of D=(A+B)/4+C.The ISA of the processor has the following set of instructions:
MOV,ADD,SUB,MUL,DIV,LOAD,STORE and a register file of 4 registers R1,R2,R3,R4.
I am having trouble starting the assembly code.I know that you have to load A,B,C into the register file first so
we get:
LOAD R1,A
LOAD R2,B
LOAD R3,C

then we have to add R1+R2 so
ADD R4,R1,R2

then divide by 4
DIV R4,4
then add C
ADD R1,R4,R3

then store the result in D
STORE D,R1

but I am not sure if it is correct.Any help?

Are you not missing an extra move instruction? To move 4 into some register?

$$
$$
$$
\text{The math you mentioned is: } D = \frac{(A + B)}{4} + C
$$
$$
\text{here are steps to calculate it in assembly:}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
1. &\ \text{Load } A, B, \text{ and } C \text{ into registers.} \\
2. &\ \text{Add } A \text{ and } B \text{ together.} \\
3. &\ \text{Divide the sum by } 4. \\
4. &\ \text{Add } C \text{ to the result.} \\
5. &\ \text{Store the final result } D.
\end{aligned}
$$
so basically in code  :

LOAD R1, A       ; Load A into R1
LOAD R2, B       ; Load B into R2
LOAD R3, C       ; Load C into R3
ADD R4, R1, R2   ; Add R1 (A) and R2 (B), store result in R4
DIV R4, 4        ; Divide R4 (A + B) by 4
ADD R1, R4, R3   ; Add R4 ((A + B)/4) and R3 (C), store result in R1
STORE D, R1      ; Store final result in D


hope this helps (:
